# How can I set a cell to TRUE|FALSE with PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to set a cell value to `TRUE` or `FALSE` with PhpSpreadsheet 1.16.0, but the result is not what I want.

My code:

```
    $sheet->getCell('A1')
        ->setValueExplicit(true, DataType::TYPE_BOOL);
```

This is what I get when I open the file with LibreOffice Calc 7.0 or 7.1:

[image]

As you can see, the cell shows a formula `=TRUE()` (or `=FALSE()`) instead of the native XLSX "boolean" type.

The cell itself has type "Number", instead of the expected "Boolean Value":

[image]

This looks easy enough, but I can't figure it out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Excel it works as expected. This is probably a bug in LibreOffice.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1833#issuecomment-777409629